# Doubts on proving there are only $2$ abelian groups of order $12$, up to isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

I have been tasked with the following exercise:

> - Prove there are only $2$ abelian groups of order $12$, up to isomorphism.

I have read some texts and watched some videos but got very confused. I want to understand what is the "algorithm" for doing it. I think it's the following:

- Due to Lagrange's theorem, a group of order $12$ could have subgroups of orders $1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12$.
- Now, if one element of this group has order $12$, then it is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_{12}$.

**Question:** What do we do now? I think we should do the following:

- Suppose there is no element of order $12$, now we try to eliminate the remaining cases using Cauchy's theorem, Sylow theorems and certain considerations about groups. For example: If we have a subgroup of order $3$ and a subgroup of order $4$, then we must have an element of order $12$ and hence, this case must be discarded because it goes against what we assumed?

Is that it? I am asking because a lot of the material I read/saw until now do not state what are the "worthy" cases we should investigate and what cases are "unworthy" of investigation, such as the one I pointed out.

Comment: I mean you could invoke http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/StructureTheoremProof.pdf

Comment: @User203940 I think we need to actually verify without that.

Comment: I'd invoke the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group). It is a bit of a sledgehammer though.

Comment: Since you mention the Sylow theorems, note the fact that these immediately imply that any finite abelian group $G$ has unique Sylow-$p$ subgroups for any prime $p$, and that $G$ is the direct product of these Sylow-$p$ subgroups. This should help to reduce the number of cases to be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Hold on while I get out my sledgehammer: By the FTFAG, it's the product of cyclic groups.  Then the only possibilities are $C_2\times C_6$ and $C_{12}$.

Comment: The trouble for me is that I cant use that, I have to "manually" find the groups.

Comment: I  saw that comment of yours.  I don't know why you would be expected to re-invent the wheel here.  However, I suppose you might be able to do so.  The group should be the direct product of its Sylow subgroups (as suggested), which are of orders $4$ and $3$.  There are only two groups of order $4$ and one of order $3$.  So either you have $V_4\times C_3$ or $C_4\times C_3\cong C_{12}$.

Comment: I have to do it that way because this is an exercise on using Sylow/Cauchy thorems.

Comment: So be it.  I guess this makes sense, especially when learning the subject.